# C++ Variables Losing Assignment Inside "if" Loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested, switch-statement, variable-assignment

So this is a very simple problem I'm sure, but I'm just starting out.

In the program, there is simple input validation. If inputed is entered properly, no issues.

The problem is, when testing the program with an error, like entering a zero or negative number, all the variables are blank (i.e., strings become blank and numbers become zero) in the output.

Thanks ahead of time for the help and insight.

```
// This menu driven program determines the time sound will take to travel through
// gas, liquid, and solid, given a distance from a user.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// constants
const double    AIR_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND = 1100.0,       //in feet per second
                WATER_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND = 4900.0,     // in feet per second
                STEEL_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND = 16400.0;    // in feet per second

// Program defined variables
double          Time_To_Travel = 0.0;       // in seconds

string          Medium;

// User defined variables
double          distance_of_travel; //in feet

int             menu_selection;

//Display a menu for mediums of sound conduction.
cout << "Sound travels at different speeds through air, water, and steel." << endl;
cout << "\nThis program will calculate the time it takes, in feet per second, for " \
"sound to travel a given distance." << endl;
cout << "Please select a number choice below:\n\n1. Air\n2. Water\n3. Steel " << endl;

//Get input from user.
cout << "\nEnter Selection: ";
cin >> menu_selection;

cout << "\nEnter distance in feet the sound will travel: ";
cin >> distance_of_travel;


// Input validate selection is on the menu
if (menu_selection >= 1 && menu_selection <= 3)
    {
    if (distance_of_travel > 0.0)  // input validation distance is positive
        {
        switch (menu_selection)  // calculate the time of travel based on user input
            {
            case 1: Medium = "air";
                    Time_To_Travel = distance_of_travel / AIR_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND;
                break;

            case 2: Medium = "water";
                    Time_To_Travel = distance_of_travel / WATER_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND;
                break;

            case 3: Medium = "steel";
                    Time_To_Travel = distance_of_travel / STEEL_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND;
                break;
            }
        }
    else
        {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a distance greater than zero: ";
        cin >> distance_of_travel;
        }
    }

else
    {
    cout << "\nMenu selection is not 1, 2, or 3.\n\nPlease correctly enter a number 1 through 3: ";
    cin >> menu_selection;
    }
// Format to four decimal places and display the time sound takes to travel given distance.
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);
cout << "Sound would take " << Time_To_Travel << " seconds to travel given distance of " << distance_of_travel << " feet in " << Medium << "." << endl;;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code in a debugger?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `if loop`. If you want a loop, use `while` or `for`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I'll remember

Comment: @MrEricSir I'm not quite sure how to run the debugger in Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` statement is a simple branch, not a loop. At the end of the `if`, execution continues past the end of the block.

```
if (menu_selection >= 1 && menu_selection <= 3)
```

This, when false, will skip the meat of your program and jump to your code that handles invalid input.

```
else
{
    cout << "\nMenu selection is not 1, 2, or 3.\n\nPlease correctly enter a number 1 through 3: ";
    cin >> menu_selection;
}
```

After you input `menu_selection` again, control flows to

```
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);
cout << "Sound would take " << Time_To_Travel << " seconds to travel given distance of " << distance_of_travel << " feet in " << Medium << "." << endl;;
return 0;
```

The new input is never acted on, and the untouched values are printed. Replace the initial `if` with a `do {...} while(condition);` loop that wraps the user input. Once the input is satisfactory, you can then proceed to the core of the program.

```
bool is_good;
do
{
    is_good = false;
    cout << "\nEnter Selection: ";
    cin >> menu_selection;
    cout << "\nEnter distance in feet the sound will travel: ";
    cin >> distance_of_travel;
    if (menu_selection < 1 || menu_selection > 3 || distance_of_travel < 0)
        cout << "error message here";
    else
        is_good = true;
} while (!is_good);
```

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I edited it to display when something was entered incorrectly.

Comment: I reciprocated my appreciation and thanks by up voting your excellent answer.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 Glad I could help!

Comment: Also remember to flush the input buffer and clear the error flag if some wiseguy types in hopelessly invalid garbage.

Comment: Whenever I try to flush the input buffer, I get stuck in an infinite loop. `istream` is the bane of my existence.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle zero, negative number, or all possible inputs that are not defined in your `case` block by adding `default` block to your switch statement. Then your code will look like something like this.

```
switch (menu_selection)  // calculate the time of travel based on user input
        {
        case 1: Medium = "air";
                Time_To_Travel = distance_of_travel / AIR_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND;
            break;

        case 2: Medium = "water";
                Time_To_Travel = distance_of_travel / WATER_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND;
            break;

        case 3: Medium = "steel";
                Time_To_Travel = distance_of_travel / STEEL_SPEED_RATE_PER_SECOND_SOUND;
            break;
        default:
            // handle zero, negative numbers and so on.
            break;
        }
```

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm

Comment: The OP already had caught invalid data (btw this solution won't catch an invalid `distance_of_travel`), but was having difficulty handling it.